# Hide DIV after click (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list item that displays a hidden div once its clicked. I want to be able to hide the div if the list item is click on again. How can I do this?

```
$(function () {
    "use strict";
    function resetTabs() {
        $("#sub_content > div").hide(); //Hide all content
        $("#tabs a").removeClass("current"); //Reset id's
    }

    $("#sub_content > div").hide(); // Initially hide all content

    $("#tabs a").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        resetTabs();
        $(this).addClass("current"); // Activate this
        $($(this).attr('name')).fadeIn(); // Show content for current tab
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E9mPw/

Thanks.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/toggle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just can add "if" statement, if you just want to fix your script

```
$("#tabs a").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).hasClass('current')){            
    resetTabs();
    }
    else{
    resetTabs();
    $(this).addClass("current"); // Activate this
        $($(this).attr('name')).fadeIn(); // Show content for current tab
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E9mPw/7/

Answer (score 3):

You can use fadeToggle()

```
$($(this).attr('name')).fadeToggle();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E9mPw/2/

Comment: Only problem is that if you click on one div and try to open the other it doesn't hide the first div.

Comment: @Chris For this case, you could use some identifier on the link and on the div. Then, when the link is clicked, the script takes this identifier and hide the specific div.

Answer (score 0):

You can use toggle jquery properties.

```
$("#tabs a").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    resetTabs();
    $(this).toggle("current");
});
```

[You chould check this links](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the a has the class current and fade it out accordingly:

```
$("#tabs a").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //resetTabs();

    if($(this).hasClass("current"))
    {
       $(this).removeClass("current");
       $($(this).attr('name')).fadeOut(); // Hide content for current tab
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).addClass("current"); // Activate this
        $($(this).attr('name')).fadeIn(); // Show content for current tab
    }
});
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E9mPw/6/)